# Squid Proxy + Content filtering + Gateway

Tags: proxy, squid, gateway

Ive been trying to understand the requirements for a proxy server with content filtering software in a given network. My main confusion is whether or not this sort of server needs to be a gateway having dual nics for wan and lan or not. In other words, can I have a server on the same network as my clients and configure squid with dansguardian using one network card? If the answer is that it does not need to be a gateway, would there be a way to filter and block https traffic as well? Most of the how-tos' found online are with using pfsense (obviously as a gateway) and installing proxy and content filtering packages on top.

Comment: Don't play with https traffic.

Comment: AFAIK `dansguardian` is basically abandonware.  It probably wouldn't be a good idea to use that in a new setup.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run an HTTP proxy+cache+filter on the border device, but it makes the setup a bit simpler.

If you aren't running it on the border device then you have to do work to get your clients to send their requests to the proxy.  This could by done through WPAD, group policies on a Windows network, some kind of configuration management system.

If you intend on filtering HTTPS, then you are going to be required to configure clients, since you must push a CA certificate in to the local certificate stores so that you filter can MITM the HTTPS traffic and do any content filtering.  So configuring the clients to use the proxy might not be too bad.

As for the setup, on a non gateway device, it is pretty straight forward.  Just install the required software on the proxy server.  On your firewall block all output http/https traffic except for traffic that comes from the proxy server.  Then configure your clients to use the proxy server.

Comment: The implications of HTTPS filtering in explicit (browser aware) mode and implicit (transparent or intercept) mode are described in article http://docs.diladele.com/administrator_guide_4_5/https_filtering/how.html. In short - explicit mode is always better as you need to configure all clients with Root CA certificate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy gateway does not have to be on the network border. The clients just have to be using it as their gateway to the web. The proxy machine itself can use another real gateway for outgoing connections.

The most common option is to configure the clients so the proxy is their default gateway router. Which relays all non-HTTP to the real border gateway router, and NAT's the HTTP through the proxy.

There are several alternative options listed in the Squid official documentation http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/IptablesPolicyRoute. In these setups the real border gateway machinery routes the client traffic via a proxy machine and only lets traffic from that machine out.

Multiple NIC's is optional regardless of the configuration. It is a nice way to simplify the routing rules (interface based intead of packet marking), or to raise the amount of traffic the machine can handle. The traffic going over a single NIC from this machine will be twice that of any normal machine. That may or may not matter for you.